# Git on Launchpad

Tags: launchpad, git, bazaar

I develop most of my code in Git repos, now that I've become slightly more active on Launchpad I've started picking up Bazaar which has two "small" difference from Git's workflow that ride against how I usually develop code. While I don't mind using Bazaar I've noticed that Launchpad has options to use multiple VSC tools

[image]

I'm curious exactly how this works with Launchpad with an emphasis on the following:

- Is the repo mirrored as a Git repo or a Bazaar repository?
- If it's a Bazaar repo - how are multiple branches in a Git repository mirrored on Launchpad?
- How are updates from users pushing to the LP branch handled

  - Are the branches from Git considered Read-only or will LP attempt to push them to the Git server?

    - If so under what methods? (Git+SSH, Git Daemon, etc)
- How often is the LP mirror updated?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The repository is stored as a bazaar repository on Launchpad.

Multiple git branches are not currently imported - this is being looked at & can be followed at https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad-code/+bug/380871

Writing to the branches on launchpad is not supported, according to http://blog.launchpad.net/code/git-branch-imports-now-in-public-beta

From what I've seen of import history for projects, the branch mirror is updated every 4-6 hours.

Comment: Launchpad doesn't push changes back to git.  Someone with credentials to write to the upstream git repo can pull or merge from Launchpad using `bzr-git` and push to the git server.

Comment: And how about mercurial?

Comment: Mercurial is the same.

Answer (score 8):

Note that recently git support was added to launchpad:
http://blog.launchpad.net/general/git-code-hosting-beta

Comment: Great news! Can be accessed from the [project page](https://launchpad.net/cirosantilli-test), "Configuration options" > ["Code"](https://launchpad.net/cirosantilli-test/+configure-code)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to push to it: http://superuser.com/questions/954490/launchpad-says-i-dont-have-an-ssh-key-but-i-do